# Can't find out how to implement apply method for binaryOperator interface java

Tags: java, apply, binary-operators

I need to implement an apply method using a binaryOperator to exectue a mathematical procedure over two doubles, but cannot find out how to. The purpose of my code is to apply the apply-method on two numbers at a time, each from it's respective iterator.

I haven't been programming for too long, so my code probably has a lot of mistakes, but this is how far I've come 'til now:

```
package interfaces;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator; 
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

public class BinaryComputingIterator implements Iterator<Double>, 
                                            BinaryOperator<Double>{
private BinaryOperator<Double> operator;

private Iterator<Double> iterator1;
private Iterator<Double> iterator2;
private Double default1;
private Double default2;

BinaryComputingIterator(Iterator<Double> iterator1, 
        Iterator<Double> iterator2, BinaryOperator<Double> operator){
    this.iterator1 = iterator1;
    this.iterator2 = iterator2;
    this.operator = operator;
}

BinaryComputingIterator(Iterator<Double> iterator1, 
        Iterator<Double> iterator2, Double default1, Double default2,
        BinaryOperator<Double> operator){
    this.iterator1 = iterator1;
    this.iterator2 = iterator2;
    this.operator = operator;
    this.default1 = default1;
    this.default2 = default2;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if (iterator1.hasNext() && iterator2.hasNext()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public Double next() {
    if (this.hasNext()){
        return this.next();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override

public Double apply(Double t, Double u) {
    return this.operator.apply(t, u);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Iterator` should *not* implement `BinaryOperator`. Your next() method should be implemented as

```
 public Double next() {
   if (hasNext()) {
     return operator.apply(iterator1.next(), iterator2.next());
   } else {
     throw new NoSuchElementException(); // specified in the Iterator contract
   }
 }
```

That should pretty much cover it.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!